# Getting oracle error sys.dbms_prvtaqis sequence does not exists

Tags: oracle

I am getting this error in oracle database while running a function.

`sys.dbms_prvtaqis sequence does not exists`

I have not used DBMS_PRVTAQIS package in my code anywhere .

DBMS_PRVTAQIS seems to be system package, the code of which is not visible to us.

Which sequence is it complaining about  and how can we resolve this error ?

Comment: Please [edit] the question and include a [MRE] with: the code that you are using that generates that error; and a complete stack trace for the error; and details of where you found that error (was it a log file, was it in the console when you run some code, etc.). You may not explicitly call that sequence but some code that you are using is calling it and you need to give us more information as to where you found the exception as we can't debug things that we cannot see.